# How to override a function that is used in a class without overriding the class

Tags: python

take this as an example file1:

```py
def _foo_prn():
    print("file1::foo.prn")

class foo(object):
    def prn(self):
        _foo_prn()
```

I want to somehow instantiate `foo` in file2 but override `_foo_prn` and get this output for example:

```py
def _foo_prn():
    print("This is my preferred output.")

myfoo = foo()
myfoo.prn()

# Output: This is my preferred output.
```

Is this possible?
Or maybe I have to rewrite the class?

Note: file1 is within a package I install with pip. so I'm not able to make modifications to it.

Comment: Inherit the class, override the method, instantiate child class, call method.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-overriding-in-python/

Comment: Thank you nail. this solution is currently on the table. so you mean that it's the only solution? @Neil

Comment: There's never only one solution. This is the obvious one. I dunno why people are suggesting monkeypatching and what what.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "monky patching" which saves the state of previous function.

```
import Foo
foo =Foo()
foo._foo_prn = _foo_prn
foo.prn() #this is call the overridden method
```

Comment: monkey patch what? class Foo doesn't have _foo_prn method. it's been defined out of class scope as a function. can you update your example if you insist?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `_foo_prn` be a class method and then monkeypatch it on `myfoo`:

```
class Foo:
    def prn(self):
        self._foo_prn()

    def _foo_prn(self):
        print("file1::foo.prn")


def _foo_prn():
    print("This is my preferred output.")


myfoo = Foo()
myfoo._foo_prn = _foo_prn
myfoo.prn()
```

Comment: sorry, check the note I just added